# Align of the x coords in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have this code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=Retraso,ylabel=Autocorrelación,ybar,bar width=1pt]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,15}{
        \addplot [color=blue,fill=blue] coordinates{
            (\x,0.8^\x)
        };
    } 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But when I compile it I have this

[image]

I want to align the `x` coordinates with the bars. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `ycomb` instead of `bar`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=Retraso,ylabel=Autocorrelación]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,15}{
        \addplot [color=blue,fill=blue,ycomb,line width=2pt] coordinates{
            (\x,0.8^\x)
        };
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=Retraso,ylabel=Autocorrelación,ybar,bar width=1pt,samples at={0,...,15}]
     \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] {0.8^\x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]